# Duplicate Django model instance without modifying python object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a method to duplicate a model instance

```py
new_object = old_object.duplicate_in_db()
```

According to [Django 3.2 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances) model instance can be duplicated in database by setting entity pk and/or id to None :

```py
# Model method
def duplicate_in_db(self):
    self.pk = None
    self._state.adding = True
    # Some other duplication steps happens here e.g. duplicating OneToOneFields attributes
    # ...    
    self.save()
```

However a side effect is that original object has its id changed (along other attributes...)

```py
old_object_pk = old_object.pk
new_object = old_object.duplicate_in_db()
print(old_object_pk == old_object.pk) # False
```

What would be an effective duplicate method/function without any side effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing from db with correct id do the job, Downside is having to do multiple database call.

```
    def duplicate_from_db(self):
        old_pk = self.pk  # storing for refreshing latter 
        self.pk = None
        self._state.adding = True
        self.save()
        new_pk = self.pk
        self.pk = old_pk
        self.refresh_from_db()
        return MyModel.objects.get(pk=new_pk)
```